# Robert April in the alternate timeline

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-2009, uss-enterprise, star-trek-tas

Although it wasn't always official, for many years it *has* been an accepted part of Star Trek canon that **[Robert April](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Robert_April)** was the first captain of the USS Enterprise (NCC-1701).  April was first introduced in *The Animated Series*, and he has since become a Star Trek fact as far as the Prime timeline is concerned.  He took command of the newly-constructed starship in 2245, taking it on its first 5-year mission, before being succeeded by Christopher Pike, James Kirk, and eventually Spock.

In the alternate Star Trek timeline stemming from *Star Trek* (2009), the Enterprise is constructed a decade later than in the Prime timeline — **[2255](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/USS_Enterprise_%28alternate_reality%29)** to be exact, and Christopher Pike is its first captain rather than April.

According to Robert April's Memory Alpha biography (linked above), he was born in 2195.  Likely, he attended Starfleet Academy in the late 2210s or the early 2220s.  In any case, he would have certainly been a Starfleet officer by the time of Nero's incursion, if not a captain of a vessel.

**Is there any information, canonical or not, on April's career in the alternate timeline?**

In terms of alternate timeline canon, we only have *Star Trek: Countdown*, *Star Trek*, and *Star Trek Into Darkness* to go on.  Neither of the two films mentions April, and I do not own *Countdown* and have not read it fully. **Does April receive mention in any original novels, novelizations, comic books, or other media, with regards to the alternate timeline?**

Comment: He isn't mentioned in either of the novelisations for Star Trek  or Star Trek : Into Darkness.

Comment: @Richard : Thanks for checking.  By the way, I've been meaning to ask you: did you already have all of your Star Trek novels scanned before your became active on SCIFI.se, or did becoming active on SCIFI.se motivate you to scan them all?

Comment: I had many of them. When I became active here, it motivated me to fill the gaps in my collection. I've become something of a trek novel jackdaw, the more obscure the better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Within the Abramsverse, Captain April appears in only one officially licensed source, the "[Countdown to Darkness](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Countdown_to_Darkness)" comic prequel series issued by IDW. In it, we learn that he captained a ship called the Enterprise that was constructed *between* the NX-01 and the present USS Enterprise seen in the new Star Trek films. His death was apparently faked and he's been playing general on a pre-warp planet.

[image]

[image]

[image]

It may also interest you to know that (according to [this 2013 webchat from the official Star Trek website](http://trekmovie.com/2013/05/20/sticky-into-darkness-open-week-thread-polls/). Robert Orci (the screenwriter for Star Trek and Star Trek : Into Darkness) indicated that he briefly toyed with the idea of making the villain of the second film a "rogue" Robert April.

> Q. **Can you tell us if you considered any other original series
>   villains for the film? Did you ever consider Gary Mitchell? Forgive me
>   if this is already been asked.**
>
> **Bob Orci.** *[I] Considered a rogue Robert April. [I] never considered Mitchell.  [I] just couldn't my mind an ultimate villain
>   named Gary. Imagine the trailer*
>
> *In the history of the Galaxy, evil has had many names… Darth Vader… Khan… now, prepare for the greatest foe ever faced by humanity…GARY…
>   ;)*

Comment: Perfect.  I was looking for something exactly like this.